# Kotlin multiplatform: kotlinx.coroutines.test library not visible in commonTest module

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-multiplatform

I have difficulties integrating kotlin testing framework for coroutines `kotlinx.coroutines.test` with multiplatform project that targets Android (and ios in the future)

My common code relies heavily on coroutines  but I'm unable to test them (it looks like the testing library is not in the classpath)

`build.gradle` for common module:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform'
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
    defaultConfig {
        compileSdkVersion 28
        javaCompileOptions.annotationProcessorOptions.includeCompileClasspath = true
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkAllWarnings true
    }
}

def coroutinesVersion = "1.3.0-M2"
def mockKVersion = "1.9.3"

kotlin {
    targets {
        fromPreset(presets.android, 'android')
    }

    sourceSets {
        commonMain.dependencies {
            //Kotlin
            implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:$kotlin_version"
            implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version" //used in Log implementation
            implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-common:$coroutinesVersion"
        }
        commonTest.dependencies {
            //Kotlin
            implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-common:$kotlin_version"
            implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-annotations-common:$kotlin_version"
            //Coroutines testing
            implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-common:$coroutinesVersion"
            implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:$coroutinesVersion"
            implementation "io.mockk:mockk-common:$mockKVersion"
        }
        androidMain.dependencies {
            implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
            implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$coroutinesVersion"
        }
        androidTest.dependencies {
            implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:$kotlin_version"
            implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:$kotlin_version"
            implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$coroutinesVersion"
            implementation "io.mockk:mockk:$mockKVersion"
        }
    }
}

/*
* Due to the current limitations, it requires that the Android target is created before the kapt dependencies are configured,
* which needs to be done in a top-level dependencies { ... } block rather than within Kotlin source sets dependencies.
*/
dependencies {
    implementation 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2'
    kapt 'com.google.auto.factory:auto-factory:1.0-beta6@jar'
    compileOnly "com.google.auto.factory:auto-factory:1.0-beta6"
}
```

Example test in `commonTest` source set:

```
package some.package.common.test

import kotlin.test.Test
import kotlin.test.assertTrue

class SomeTest {

    @Test
    fun `should pass`() {
        //none of the kotlinx.coroutines.test content is available here (eg. runBlockingTest)
        assertTrue { 2 + 2 == 4 }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello! Maybe you got to change `implementation` with `testImplementation`, like in the (README)?[https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/kotlinx-coroutines-test/README.md]

Comment: Hello. It seems that testImplementation keyword does not work for common dependencies.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It turns out that `kotlinx.coroutines.test` is a JVM library, so it can’t be used in common module.

Possible solutions:

- Write tests and use the library in Android (or other JVM compatible) module
- Define your own common function that will use JVM/Native implementation of runBlocking (see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-22228)

---

```
//TestUtil.kt in commonTest source set
expect fun runBlocking(block: suspend () -> Unit)

//TestUtil.kt in androidTest source set
actual fun runBlocking(block: suspend () -> Unit) = kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking { block() }

//example usage in commonTest source set
class Test {
    @Test
    fun shouldPass() = runBlocking {
        assertTrue { 2 + 2 == 4 }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it looks like they've [fixed it](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1996#issuecomment-975431270). Right now, you should be able to use kotlinx.coroutines.test inside your commonTest.
As far as I get it, with the new Kotlin 1.6 release you should be able to use [this](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/kotlinx-coroutines-test#accessing-the-test-coroutine-scope) to run your tests in the shared KMM code